When i try to run dev server its is giving me this
X [ERROR] Expected identifier but found "import"
(define name):1:0:
  1 │ import.meta.dirname
    ╵ ~~~~~~

X [ERROR] Expected identifier but found "import"
(define name):1:0:
  1 │ import.meta.filename
    ╵ ~~~~~~

X [ERROR] Expected identifier but found "import"
(define name):1:0:
  1 │ import.meta.url
    ╵ ~~~~~~

failed to load config from C:\MERN\Reactjs\Password\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: Build failed with 3 errors:
(define name):1:0: ERROR: Expected identifier but found "import"
(define name):1:0: ERROR: Expected identifier but found "import"
(define name):1:0: ERROR: Expected identifier but found "import"
at failureErrorWithLog (C:\MERN\Reactjs\Password\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1476:15)
at C:\MERN\Reactjs\Password\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:945:25
at runOnEndCallbacks (C:\MERN\Reactjs\Password\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1316:45)
at buildResponseToResult (C:\MERN\Reactjs\Password\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:943:7)
at C:\MERN\Reactjs\Password-Manager\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:970:16
at responseCallbacks. (C:\MERN\Reactjs\Password-\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:622:9)
at handleIncomingPacket (C:\MERN\Reactjs\Password-\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:677:12)
at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\MERN\Reactjs\Password-\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:600:7)
at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
I am trying to run but it is showing error

The problem seems to be with esbuild version 0.24.1
Downgrading to 0.24.0 will solve the error for now
npm i -D esbuild@0.24.0
